# Using callback function of button in a widget that is not in the build method

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently have this code from the flutter samples:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'auth.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({this.auth, this.onSignedOut});

  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback onSignedOut;

  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _HomePageState();


}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  void signOut() async {
    try {
      await widget.auth.signOut();
      widget.onSignedOut();

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }


  @override
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
   List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Hero(
      tag: "Login-Homepage",
      child: Container(
        child: new Text('Hello'),
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'Lessons will go here',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Tasks will go here',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Container(
      child: new RaisedButton(
        child: new Text('Sign Out'),
        onPressed: signOut,
      ),
    )

  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.1,
        title: const Text(
          'Musiplan - Teachers Dash',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: Text('Dashboard'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
            title: Text('Lessons'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.book),
            title: Text('Tasks'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            title: Text('Settings'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Color(0xff455eba),
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, running this code leaves me with `Only static members can be accessed in initializers.` on the `onPressed: signout` property of the button. I'm trying to call that function on the press of that button to call that function, but I am stuck on the errors that it is giving me. Changing the function to `static void` only leaves me with more errors.

Is there any way that I can get around this issue?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you're accessing some method in an initializer (when you're creating the list of widgets, that is an initializer).
Try to create the list of widgets in the initState method instead.

```
  List<Widget> _widgetOptions;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
      Hero(
        tag: "Login-Homepage",
        child: Container(
          child: new Text('Hello'),
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        'Lessons will go here',
        style: optionStyle,
      ),
      Text(
        'Tasks will go here',
        style: optionStyle,
      ),
      Container(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Sign Out'),
          onPressed: signOut,
        ),
      )
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Great, that fixed it. Thanks a lot!